# python not in apt cache

Tags: python, ubuntu, apt

I am having an issue that it seems like `python` is not in my apt cache. This is hindering my ability to use an open-source package (https://github.com/osrf/py3-ready) that relies on having `python` in the apt cache.

To give a brief summary/explanation - I am running Ubuntu 20.04 and have both python2.7 and python3.8. The alias for python is set to python2.7. when I run `sudo apt-cache search python` I found that `python3` is cached, but not `python`. Seeing as how this open source application looks for `python` in the apt cache, I am unsure as to how to fix this issue in general to have `python` show up on my apt cache.

Thank you for any help!

Comment: I think the README tells you what you need to do, did you install the packages it tells to install?

Comment: Yes, followed the instructions for `python3`, as for `python` those packages do not exist on Ubuntu 20.04. So I did install `python-apt`, which is curious as to why it is not showing up on the apt cache